# jQuery or JS transformation of dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to find a `TABLE` within a `DIV` tag and perform modifications on the header. The available reporting tool does not allow to identify the generated table but allows script and `DIV` insertion.

Consider the table below where the header is the first line:

```
<div id="ScrollHeader">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Browser</td>
      <td>Visits</td>
      <td>Pages/Visit</td>
      <td>Avg. Time on Site</td>
      <td>% New Visits</td>
      <td>Bounce Rate</td>
      <td>Avg. Time on Site</td>
      <td>% New Visits</td>
      <td>Bounce Rate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firefox first</td>
      <td>1,990</td>
      <td>3.11</td>
      <td>00:04:22</td>
      <td>70.00%</td>
      <td>32.61%</td>
      <td>00:04:22</td>
      <td>70.00%</td>
      <td>32.61%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firefox</td>
      <td>1,990</td>
      <td>3.11</td>
      <td>00:04:22 test test test</td>
      <td>70.00%</td>
      <td>32.61%</td>
      <td>00:04:22</td>
      <td>70.00%</td>
      <td>32.61%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need a JavaScript or jQuery code to transform the table to the following:

```
<div id="ScrollHeader">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Visits</th>
        <th>Pages/Visit</th>
        <th>Avg. Time on Site</th>
        <th>% New Visits</th>
        <th>Bounce Rate</th>
        <th>Avg. Time on Site</th>
        <th>% New Visits</th>
        <th>Bounce Rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Firefox first</td>
      <td class="numeric">1,990</td>
      <td class="numeric">3.11</td>
      <td class="numeric">00:04:22</td>
      <td class="numeric">70.00%</td>
      <td class="numeric">32.61%</td>
      <td class="numeric">00:04:22</td>
      <td class="numeric">70.00%</td>
      <td class="numeric">32.61%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The code needs to identify the table within `<div id="ScrollHeader">`, insert `THEAD` before the first `TR`, change the `TD` to `TH` in the first line and close it with  `</thead>`.

I have tried using `$("div p[id^='ScrollHeader']").length` to find the `DIV` and `$("tr:first")` to perform `<table>.prepend(document.createElement('thead'));` without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#ScrollHeader table tr:eq(0)').wrap('<thead />');
$('#ScrollHeader table tr:eq(0) td').each(function () {
    $('#ScrollHeader table tr:eq(0)').append($('<th />').html($(this).html()));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! It works fine. What command will add an ID to the table within the DIV? $table.find("table").replaceWith("table ID='myTable'")

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ScrollHeader tr:first')
    .wrap('<thead />')
    .children().each(function(){
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<th>'+text+'</th>');
    });
$('#ScrollHeader thead').insertBefore('#ScrollHeader tbody');
```

you can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ppNPD/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! It works fine. What command will add an ID to the table within the DIV? $table.find("table").replaceWith("table ID='myTable'")

Comment: Try this: `$('#ScrollHeader table').attr('id', 'myTable');`

Comment: Valmir: Matías already answered you about the assignment of an ID to the table, so I won't answer that one. As a good Stackoverflow user, you should upvote the answers who helped you and accept the answer that was the best solution to your problem. :)